# I can't find System.Windows.Media namespace

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2012, assemblies

I can't seem to find `System.Windows.Media` reference for my C# project. It is not there at all!

Help and tips?
[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`System.Windows.Media` is a *namespace* - most of the types within it are in the *assembly* `PresentationFramework.dll` or `PresentationCore.dll`.

You should look up whichever type you're interested in (via MSDN), and check which assembly it's in. You've got to distinguish between namespaces and assemblies - they're different concepts. You add a *reference* to an assembly as part of the project configuration, but specify the *namespace* in your source code (usually via a `using` directive).

Answer (score 4):

[`System.Windows.Media`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Media.aspx) is not a *reference*, it is a [`namespace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k.aspx).

This namespace belongs on `PresentationFramework.dll` or `PresentationCore.dll`

```
Namespace:  System.Windows.Media
Assembly:  PresentationFramework (in PresentationFramework.dll)
```

You can add these *dll* files in your current project and then you can use it via [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx).

```
using System.Windows.Media;
```