# How to locate the file of the assembly containing a specified class?

Tags: powershell, .net-core

I am on Windows 10, and want to capture images from my webcam in PowerShell Core using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/capture-photos-and-video-with-cameracaptureui).

How do I locate the physical assembly file that houses `Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUI` so that I can do an `Add-Type`?

Comment: For the specific type, the answer is in https://stackoverflow.com/q/17677168/45375. For a type that is already loaded, use `.Assembly.Location` (e.g., `[object].Assembly.Location`). Otherwise, there is no easy way that I know of - the docs usually don't tell you. _Sometimes_, the assembly name is the same as the namespace, but there is no guaranteed relationship between the two.